# Angular CLI - ng serve won't run unless I specify port

Tags: angular-cli

I have an application generated with Angular CLI running on a Ubuntu box.  When I run:

```
ng serve
```

From the project's root directory, everything works, except that I can't load the load the application in my browser when I navigated to:

```
http://host.domain.tld:4200/
```

However, when I run:

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4201 --live-reload-port 49153
```

Then I the application loads in my browser.

How can I configure the application to be accessible on the dev server by just running "ng serve"?

Comment: are you running the project on the same machine or is it on a server and you are executing the command using SSH ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dev server prevents connections from outside as a security precaution. If you wish to run the dev server without it being blocked run

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check
```

Comment: The option '--host 0.0.0.0' is not registered with the serve command.

Answer (score 1):

you can go edit your package.json file and change this line: 
`"start": "ng serve",` 
 with 
 `"start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4201 --live-reload-port 49153",` 
 and then you could just simply run `npm start`

Comment: Thanks Mostafa, however that approach is still running ng serve with the ports explicitly configured.  It's just abstracting it to an npm script.

Comment: yes I know, I just wanted to point it out just in case you didnt want to specify the port for a shorter script